# Why does the output of `lsblk` and `df -h` seem to conflict?

Tags: linux, partitioning, centos, disk-space, df

I'm trying to create a directory `/mnt/data` that will be mounted on to `/dev/mapper/centos-home`, since that's the biggest partition. The output of `lsblk` looks like this:

```
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0   430G  0 disk
├─sda1            8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2            8:2    0 429.5G  0 part
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─centos-swap 253:1    0     4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─centos-home 253:2    0 375.5G  0 lvm  /home
sdb               8:16   0   1.9G  0 disk
sdc               8:32   1  57.9G  0 disk
├─sdc1            8:33   1   7.2G  0 part /run/media/runner/CentOS 7 x86_64
    �─sdc2            8:34   1   6.1M  0 part
sr0              11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

The output of `cd /home && df -h .` looks like this:

```
/dev/mapper/centos-root   50G  8.7G   42G  18% /home
```

The way I'm reading it, is that `centos-home` is mounted on `/home`, and has 375GB of space. So why is it that when I check to see how much free space `/home` has, it's showing me the free space of `centos-root`?

Comment: On a CentOS 7 system with pretty much the same LVM setup, I get `/dev/mapper/centos-home`. Is your system up to date? Maybe this is a `df` bug that has since been fixed.

Comment: Installed the system only a few days ago from the latest CentOS release, so unfortunately I don't think it's a matter of upgrading.

Comment: What does `mount` say is mounted where? looks like they both think /home is on different places